# Azure AD B2C doesn't check if email exists

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I've an Azure AD B2C setup that no matter which email I insert in forgot password email's field it will send the verification code email to that email.

Even if the email doesn't exists in the Users list.

Is this the default behavior?

[This is the link I have for recover password](https://[tenant].b2clogin.com/[tenant].onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_SSPR&client_id=[clientId]&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=[redirectUrl]&scope=openid%20offline_access&response_type=code&prompt=login&response_mode=query)

Is there any missing property in the url that force check if the email exists in User list ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm the behavior but I couldn't find any reference on why exactly it works that way. Like many things in security, I'm pretty sure it's a design trade-off.

Some services (e.g. Evernote) do the same, i.e. they send a password reset email no matter if the address is registered with them or not.

- On the upside, this is an early alert for the user that someone is trying to get access their (nonexistent) account, so a phishing attempt coming from a different website is likely.
- The problem is that the user gets an unsolicited email message, and if somebody wants to annoy him/her, all it has to do is to send multiple reset password requests. The user is helpless, there's nothing he can do to stop the emails. So I presume the service mitigates this by limiting the number of reset password requests to a reasonable amount (say max 10/hour, but no more than 3 in any 5 minutes).

Other services (e.g. Dropbox) take the other approach and only send email messages to addresses registered with their service.

- this prevents the "email bomb" issue
- on the other hand, it doesn't alert the user about the login attempt

Like you, I would argue that the latter approach is better, as the only benefit I can see in the former one is the "early warning" issued to a user that's not even registered with your service. Also, understanding the early warning requires some user sophistication. But obviously Microsoft went the other way.

There's a Password Reset item in the Users blade, but the only options are None and All. Interestingly, the tooltip on this option mentions an nonexistent "Selected" option, so some more fine-grained settings may appear here in the future.

Comment: It seems like another downside is that an attacker could have a password email sent to an address they actually have access to as part of probing the system. In this case, getting the email gives them additional information about the system, even if only the expected format of the password reset emails in order to craft a phishing email to send a real user.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exists if the users exist before sending messages then you have to edit the SendCode Action . So it will only send verification code when user exists in B2C side.

Below is the very good link which can help you with that.
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/pwd-reset-email-exists

Comment: Can you maybe include a piece of code example. It is better to share code and then share the link example afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

It is by design. And it will try to send out the verification code without validating whether email exists or not.

By considering security measures this is how it should work.

Comment: I fail to see the security improvement in sending the reset message to an email address that's not registered, can you provide a reference or an explanation? Doesn't this expose the system to abuse (say for email bombing), thus requiring some form of rate-limiting?

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/98085 it will answer your question some extent..

Comment: User enumeration is avoided by always returning the user an "Email was sent" response, no matter if the email address is registered or not. How is this improved by always sending the email, even for email addresses that are not registered?

Comment: If attacker knows the emails of your customers then there is a chance of sensing phishing emails and your customers may become victims of the same. This leads to a big security and information leakage risk. B2C follows industry standards in best possible way to improve the security

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however wasn't able to find any documentation in Microsoft related with it